# Chaining WireGuard Servers: Can ping both from client, but can't access internet. IP routing issue?

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, routing, wireguard

I am attempting a chained/double-hop VPN setup where all client traffic passes through 2 servers before reaching the internet:

```
Client → Server1 → Server2 → Public Internet
```

All peers are on these private address blocks: `10.103.213.0/24` (IPv4) and `fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:0/112` (IPv6). Below are the configurations of the peers and the IPTables rules in place. **(Please also note the names of the configuration files, in case it matters.)**

---

### Server2 Configuration

File: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

```
# Server2

[Interface]
PrivateKey = SERVER2_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.103.213.2/24, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:2/112
ListenPort = 53701
SaveConfig = false

# CLIENTS

[Peer] # Server1
PublicKey = SERVER1_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = SERVER1_PRESHARED_KEY
# ↓ to allow traffic from client (10.103.213.11/32) via Server1 (10.103.213.1/32), allow both
AllowedIPs = 10.103.213.0/24, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:0/112
```

Firewall config. commands:

```
ufw allow 53701/udp comment 'WireGuard VPN'

iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
ip6tables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.103.213.0/24 -o enp8s0 -j MASQUERADE
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:0/112 -o enp8s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

### Server1 Configuration

File: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

```
# Server1

[Interface]
PrivateKey = SERVER1_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.103.213.1/24, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:1/112
ListenPort = 53701
SaveConfig = false

# CLIENTS

[Peer] # Server2
PublicKey = SERVER2_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = SERVER1_PRESHARED_KEY
Endpoint = SERVER2_PUBLIC_IP:53701
AllowedIPs = 10.103.213.2/32, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:2/128
#PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer] # PC
PublicKey = CLIENT_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = CLIENT_PRESHARED_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.103.213.11/32, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:11/128
```

Firewall config. commands:

```
ufw allow 53701/udp comment 'WireGuard VPN'

iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
ip6tables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

### Client Configuration

```
# CLIENT: PC

[Interface]
PrivateKey = CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.103.213.11/24, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:11/112
DNS = 10.103.213.1, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:1

[Peer] # Server1
PublicKey = SERVER1_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = CLIENT_PRESHARED_KEY
Endpoint = SERVER1_PUBLIC_IP:53701
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
#PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

---

Now, like I said, I am able to ping Server1 (`10.103.213.2`) and Server2 (`10.103.213.1`) from the Client (`10.103.213.11`) on the private (WireGuard) network when the VPN is enabled on all peers, ***but I cannot access the internet***.

I know I'm missing some much needed IP routes or IPTables rules, but despite trying to find **a solution that I can understand** for days, I've had no success. I see that there's little hope for me without actually reading a book on Linux networking/firewall.

***For now, I am hoping someone can help me with a solution along with an explanation as to what we are doing and why, so I can understand better and take notes.***

Thank you very much!

---

**NOTES:**

- If I'm missing any useful information, please ask and I'll be happy to get it.
- Client runs macOS. Server1 and Server2 run Debian 11 "Bullseye". Just an FYI, in case it's relevant.
- Server1 and Server2 have Unbound installed and set up for local DNS resolution. That's why you see `DNS = 10.103.213.1, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:1` in Client config. If not for that, I'd be using either CloudFlare or Google's IPs there.
- Someone on #wireguard IRC suggested that I try adding `Table = 123` under `[Interface]` in Server1's WireGuard config. and then running the command `ip rule add iif wg0 table 123`. That didn't work and I couldn't understand what it's supposed to do either (I couldn't make sense of the man pages or the technical details).
- From my reading I came to the conclusion that `iptables` and `ufw` can be used together—except one has to be careful when using `iptables-persistent`. You need to run `netfilter-persistent save` even after running `ufw` commands for the firewall rules to be persistent across reboots *even if* `ufw status` says they are in place. If for some reason you reboot before saving, delete the UFW rules and add them again and then run `netfilter-persistent save`.

Comment: Mixing UFW and iptables doesn't look like a good idea to me.

Comment: @iBug IDK, I did read up about it and pretty much came to the conclusion that they can be used together—except you have to be careful when using `iptables-persistent` (`netfilter-persistent save` even after running `ufw` commands). No others issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind folks over at [`#wireguard` IRC channel on Libera.Chat](https://web.libera.chat/#wireguard) helped me out!

The issues with my config. were as follows:

- Server1's config has Server2 with `AllowedIPs` of just Server2's IP addresses. That wont permit "The Internet". It needs to be `0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0`.
- Server1's WireGuard interface must be configured to add routes (for all entries in `AllowedIPs`) to a custom IP routing table (let's call it `wireguard2x`) instead of the `main` table. Then add an IP policy rule that says that traffic with the input interface (iif) `wg0` go to the custom table—which also means other kinds of traffic take the default route, per usual.

---

## Corrected Configuration

### Server2 Configuration

File: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

```
# Server2

[Interface]
PrivateKey = SERVER2_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.103.213.2/24, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:2/112
ListenPort = 53701
SaveConfig = false

# CLIENTS

[Peer] # Server1
PublicKey = SERVER1_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = SERVER1_PRESHARED_KEY
# ↓ to allow traffic from client (10.103.213.11/32) via Server1 (10.103.213.1/32), allow both
AllowedIPs = 10.103.213.0/24, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:0/112
```

Firewall config. commands:

```
ufw allow 53701/udp comment 'WireGuard VPN'

iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
ip6tables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.103.213.0/24 -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:0/112 -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

### Server1 Configuration

File: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

```
# Server1

[Interface]
PrivateKey = SERVER1_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.103.213.1/32, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:1/128
ListenPort = 53701
Table = wireguard2x
# ↓ should only be set if resolvconf or openresolv is installed on the system, otherwise let the system use defaults
# ↓ is unncessary if local DNS resolution is set up
#DNS = 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1, 2606:4700:4700::1111, 2606:4700:4700::1001
DNS = 10.103.213.1, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:1
SaveConfig = false

# CLIENTS

[Peer] # Server2
PublicKey = SERVER2_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = SERVER1_PRESHARED_KEY
Endpoint = SERVER2_PUBLIC_IP:53701
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
#PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer] # PC
PublicKey = CLIENT_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = CLIENT_PRESHARED_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.103.213.11/32, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:11/128
```

Firewall config. commands:

```
ufw allow 53701/udp comment 'WireGuard VPN'

iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT &&
ip6tables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT

echo 123 wireguard2x >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add iif wg0 table wireguard2x
```

### Client Configuration

```
# CLIENT: PC

[Interface]
PrivateKey = CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.103.213.11/32, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:11/128
DNS = 10.103.213.1, fd6f:9403:2887:9cd6:10:103:213:1

[Peer] # Server1
PublicKey = SERVER1_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = CLIENT_PRESHARED_KEY
Endpoint = SERVER1_PUBLIC_IP:53701
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
#PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

---

**NOTES:**

- You can see all the policy routing rules that are currently in effect using this command: `ip rule list` or `ip rule`
- View the routing tables with, for e.g., `ip route show table wireguard2x` or `ip route list table wireguard2x.`
- To flush the route cache: `ip route flush cache`
- Further reading: [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control (LARTC) HOWTO](https://web.archive.org/web/20211002071319/https://lartc.org/lartc.html#LARTC.RPDB)
- You can monitor Client's network traffic flow—if on Linux, using `sudo iptraf-ng`; on macOS using `sudo iftop`. (To be run on the client.)

  - I found running that hard to parse due to too many live changes. So I was suggested trying `route get 192.0.2.0` (which shows the interface being used, e.g., `interface: utun2`) and then running `ifconfig <interface>` (e.g., `ifconfig utun2`) on macOS. The latter should show the Client's private (WireGuard peer) IP address, e.g., `10.103.213.11`, confirming that the traffic is being routed through WG interface. It's not much, but it's a start.
  - **UDPATE:** `traceroute` is brilliant for this! For e.g., `traceroute 8.8.8.8`. ([Hat tip to Chrispus Kamau](https://www.ckn.io/blog/2017/12/28/wireguard-vpn-chained-setup/).)
- `curl ipinfo.io` to check your IP address with the VPN enabled. (To be run on the client.)

**RELATED:**

- https://superuser.com/a/1651179

Comment: except that AllowedIPs = 10.103.213.11/32 on one peer will clash with AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 on the other peer. Contrary to routes, there must be *no* overlap. Compute 0.0.0.0/0 minus 10.103.213.11/32  (eg with the help the netmask command) or use two different WG interfaces. The reason for this is explained there: https://www.wireguard.com/#cryptokey-routing . You can't have 10.103.213.11/32 matching two different peers (because it also matches 0.0.0.0/0)

Answer (score 0):

its_me's answer is working great for me. Below are some changes I made to automate the creation/removal of the route table, iptables and ip rules. The automation happens as the wireguard interface is brought up and down. Please note I am not using ipv6 or ufw in this configuration:

Server1:

```
# Add a route table for this interface
PreUp = echo 1 wireguard2x >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# Add ip rule to point this interface at the new route table
PreUp = ip rule add iif %i table wireguard2x
# Setup iptables
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT

# Remove the iptables
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT
# Find and remove the ip rule
PostDown = ip rule | grep "from all iif %i" | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -L1 ip rule del prio
# Remove the ip table
PostDown = sed -i '/wireguard2x/d' /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Server2:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Yep, I am aware of `PostUp` and `PostDown` in WG config. I just like all my firewall rules (including system & other app rules) to be in one place and therefore prefer adding them manually.

Comment: @computerguy1
I tried your configuration and it can connect to Server-II but eventually lost SSH access to Server-I. Moreover, I can't connect to Server-I using any WireGuard client.

Answer (score 0):

*(Based on Chrispus Kamau's excellent **Wireguard VPN** tutorials for **[Typical Setup](https://www.ckn.io/blog/2017/11/14/wireguard-vpn-typical-setup/)** and **[Chained Setup](https://www.ckn.io/blog/2017/12/28/wireguard-vpn-chained-setup/)**, it appears I may have a solution (**untested!**) in a format that shows how somewhat unusual/complex setups could be handled—or at least give you an idea. Many thanks CK!)*

Via: https://github.com/iamckn/chained-wireguard-ansible

---

**How it works:**

- Client (`vpn0`) → `10.200.200.0/24` → (`wg0`) → Middleman (`gate0`) → `10.100.100.0/24` → (`wg0`) Gate (`wg0`) → Public Internet
- Assumes that Unbound is set up on both the Middleman and Gate for local DNS resolution.

### Gate Configuration

Configure the gate's VPN interface (`wg0`).

File: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

```
# SERVER

[Interface] # Gate
PrivateKey = GATE_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.100.100.1/24
ListenPort = 53701
SaveConfig = false

# CLIENTS

[Peer] # Middleman
PublicKey = MIDDLEMAN_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = MIDDLEMAN_PRESHARED_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/8
```

Firewall config. commands:

```
# Track VPN connection
## Track input chain
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
## Track forward chain
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming WireGuard connections/VPN traffic on the listening port
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53701 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow both TCP and UDP recursive DNS traffic
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.100.100.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.100.100.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow forwarding of packets that stay in the VPN tunnel
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# Set up NAT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.100.0/24 -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Bring up the gate's VPN interface, and enable the WireGuard service to automatically restart on boot:

```
wg-quick up wg0
systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0
```

### Middleman Configuration

Configure the middleman's gate-facing interface (`gate0`). Here middleman acts as the client.

File: `/etc/wireguard/gate0.conf`

```
[Interface] # Middleman
PrivateKey = MIDDLEMAN_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.100.100.2/32
DNS = 10.100.100.1
SaveConfig = false

# PEERS

[Peer] # Gate
PublicKey = GATE_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = MIDDLEMAN_PRESHARED_KEY
Endpoint = GATE_PUBLIC_IP:53701
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
#PersistentKeepalive = 21
```

Configure the middleman's client-facing interface (`wg0`). Here middleman acts as the server.

File: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

```
# SERVER

[Interface] # Middleman
PrivateKey = MIDDLEMAN_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.200.200.1/24
ListenPort = 53701
SaveConfig = false

# CLIENTS

[Peer] # PC
PublicKey = CLIENT_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = CLIENT_PRESHARED_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.2/32
```

Firewall config. commands:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53701 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s 10.200.200.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.200.200.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.200.0/24 -o enp41s0 -j MASQUERADE

# Set up VPN chain NAT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.200.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.100.100.2
```

Configure policy routing on the middleman to route traffic from the client to the gate.

```
echo "1 middleman" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# Forward all traffic to the gate
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev gate0 table middleman

# OR only forward traffic to 4.2.2.2 (for e.g.), to the gate
#ip route add 4.2.2.2/32 dev gate0 table middleman

ip rule add from 10.200.200.0/24 lookup middleman
```

Bring up the middleman's WireGuard interfaces, and enable the WireGuard service to automatically restart on boot:

```
wg-quick up gate0
systemctl enable wg-quick@gate0

wg-quick up wg0
systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0
```

### Client Configuration

File: `/etc/wireguard/vpn0.conf`

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.200.200.2/32
DNS = 10.200.200.1

# PEERS

[Peer] # Middleman
PublicKey = MIDDLEMAN_PUBLIC_KEY
PresharedKey = CLIENT_PRESHARED_KEY
Endpoint = MIDDLEMAN_PUBLIC_IP:53701
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
#PersistentKeepalive = 21
```

Finally activate WireGuard on the client.