# Wireguard double hop

Tags: vpn, wireguard

Please help me.
I find instruction in this question: [Chaining WireGuard Servers: Can ping both from client, but can't access internet. IP routing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080901/chaining-wireguard-servers-can-ping-both-from-client-but-cant-access-internet/1123093#1123093)
and
https://allanjohn909.medium.com/vpn-chaining-with-wireguard-ec2bd500509e
https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2022/06/multi-hop-wireguard/
https://superuser.com/questions/1708311/internet-access-through-wireguard-over-multiple-hops

But i try this instruction and many another, don't work. I test that on DigitalOcean droplets Debian 10. I installed WireGuard and did all the configs, but the Internet does not work. Perhaps something else needs to be done? When gate0 is run, the droplet breaks the connection, but I completed all the other commands. Help me please. Perhaps a small algorithm of actions that would make everything work.

Thank you.

Comment: How is this relevant to managing information systems in a business environment?

Comment: sorry 
i made the wrong section